Does the value approached by a complex limit have to be unique no matter the direction of approach?
I am doing a course on Complex Analysis and we're using Churchill and Brown. I was confused about limits with complex numbers. There's a theorem that says:
When a limit of a function f (z) exists at a point $z_0$, it is unique
Does this mean that the limit has to evaluate to the same value if I approach it from the real axis, imaginary axis or an arbitrary line passing through the origin assuming the limit is
$$ \lim_{z \to 0}  f(z)  $$

As stated, the claim "when a limit of a function $f(z)$ exists at a point $z_0$, it is unique" does not mean something about the direction of approach. It means that the limit is unique in the sense that the value the  limit takes is the only value that the limit takes.
Generally, the definition of the limit says that $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) = L$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(z)-L| < \epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0| < \delta$. In this definition, one could wonder if we could have $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) = L_1$ and $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) = L_2$.  Could there be both an $L_1$ and some different number $L_2$ that are both the limit of the function. The theorem says that this can not happen, that if the limit exists and is some value $L$, it cannot be any other value.
It is true that "limit has to evaluate to the same value if I approach it from the real axis, imaginary axis or an arbitrary line passing through the origin", but that just happens to not be what this theorem, as stated, is saying.

This make so much sense! Thank you so much

If the limit of a complex function $f(z)$ exists, then it is unique, which means: if $\lim_{z \to z_0}{f(z)} = L_1$ and if $\lim_{z \to z_0}{f(z)} = L_2$, then $L_1 = L_2$.
Also, if the limit of a complex function $f(z)$ exists at some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$,then it equals the same value approaching $z_0$ from any path. This naturally leads to the following logically equivalent contrapositive: If you can find two paths to $z_0$ where $\lim_{z \to z_0}{f(z)}$ is different, then the limit does not exist.
For example, consider $\lim_{z \to 0}{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}$. Since $z = x + iy$, consider $z = x$ and let $x \to 0$. Then the limit becomes $\lim_{x \to 0}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$. This limit DNE (consider the one-sided limits), so the complex limit DNE.
